# SelectKBest ValueError after Log-Transformation of Target-Variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection, sklearn-pandas, valueerror

I am currently doing some analysis on the Housing Prices in Ames Iowa dataset.
I have successfully wrangled the data and removed all missing values etc and I'm about to do some regression analysis. I want to build three regression models the first with the two best features, the second with 15 features and the third with all available variables. I am using SelectKBest to do the feature selection. My target variable is the 'SalePrice' which I log-transformed.
I always get a value-error from SelectKBest for some reason.
Interestingly, if I do not log-transform the 'SalePrice', everything works fine.
I checked the dtype of my target variable and ist as expected a float.
Could Somebody help me out?
I would really appreciate it!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

```
SelectKBest(chi2)
```

According to the [documentation of `chi2`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html):

Parameters:

> ```
> X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = (n_samples, n_features_in)
>     Sample vectors.
>
> y : array-like, shape = (n_samples,)
>     Target vector (class labels).
> ```

`chi2` only works with classification tasks, not regression. Your current problem of predicting sales price is a regression task and hence the error.

Maybe try [`f_regression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html) in place of `chi2`